# Plotly modebar issue with responsive chart

Tags: javascript, css, plotly

trying to have a responsive chart with Plotly.js, I'm experiencing an issue:
hovering the last icon of the mode-bar, the mode-bar moves to the left and both the scrollbars where displayed, as you can see in the following [CodePen](https://codepen.io/drypatrick/pen/eYPVvqp), where I've set in the CSS:

```
html, body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            border: 0;
            outline: 0;
}

#plotly-graph {
            height: 100vh;
}
```

And in the js:

```
var config = {
  responsive: true
}
```

Any hint on how to solve this issue?

Comment: The tooltip of that button needs some room, adding `margin-right: 5px;` to `#plotly-graph` or `.modebar-container` should fix this.